Is Quine's Mathematical Logic "ML" consistent with Azcel's Extensionality?
Now that Holmes had proven the consistency of adding Extensionality to Stratified Comprehension (i.e. $\sf NF$), a question along the same vein presents itself:

Is Aczel's Extensionality axiom consistent with $\sf ML$?

In $\sf ML$ we can phrase Aczel's Extensionality as: any sets whose transitive closures are isomorphic on membership, are equal.

To be clear: you intend the axiom Aczel calls “$AFA_2$” in his book, stating that every graph has at most one decoration?

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, yes!

This might be sensitive to how you define transitive closure. In $\mathsf{NF}$, for instance, there's going to be a least transitive set containing any given set $X$ (obtained by taking the intersection of all transitive sets $Y \supseteq X$), but there might be definable transitive subclasses of this set containing $X$. In principle one might define the strong extensionality axiom using a more restrictive definition of transitive closure that isn't actually a set.

In any case, a place to look would be Thomas Forster's book Set Theory with a Universal Set, which has some discussion of strong extensionality axioms in $\mathsf{NF}$.

Actually now that I think about it that argument doesn't even establish the existence of transitive closures because the definition of transitivity isn't stratified.

What is ML, and how it relates to NF?

@JamesEHanson, transitive closures are defined using the class machinery of ML and doesn't depend on the NF part of ML. ML (like MK) proves the existence of a transitive closure for every set. The class comprehension axiom schema of ML is not stratified!

@EmilJeřábek ,  ML is Quine's Mathematical Logic. ML to NF is like MK to ZF with the difference that quantifiers must be bounded by the universe of sets in stratified comprehension of ML. See https://www.google.iq/books/edition/Mathematical_Logic_Revised_Edition/5glxwVt_srEC?hl=en&gbpv=0, see also, https://books.google.iq/books?id=NJ7SBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA300&lpg=PA300&dq=Quines%20Mathematical%20logic%20ML%20free&source=bl&ots=z9mqRJgish&sig=ACfU3U2c029nQ6ec9w7eC4TW5i3L1hk89g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_xImX_P_2AhVOtKQKHSBmANUQ6AF6BAgiEAM#v=onepage&q=Quines%20Mathematical%20logic%20ML%20free&f=false
